# why should we use rectangular supercell of graphene instead of hexagonal supercell to calculate the elastic constant (in-plane stiffness)

Tags: elasticity

Most researchers use rectangular supercells instead of hexagonal supercells of graphene to calculate the mechanical properties. All of the articles are working on mechanical properties, they considered the paper (https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3353968 ) as a reference for them.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but since it has been almost 6 months, is there any update you can provide us? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Please let us know!